# How to find Image View for Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have following this documentation here:
https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae

which is pretty useful up to the point:

> We then want to add an Image View to our splash screen. You can find
>   that by pressing the third option in the bottom right menu and
>   searching for “image”. When you’ve got that drag it onto the blue
>   View.

I am using Xcode 10.1 and I know a lot of online resources are from Xcode 8 and 9. Can anyone guide me to how to pull up that **Image View** for Xcode 10.1?

This is what I am currently seeing:

[image: current]

This is what I would like to see:

[image: expected]

I have kicked the tires, looked around for over 20 minutes and I see nothing that pulls up **Image View** so I can choose the image I desire for the splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's under the `Library`.
Refer to the following images (Xcode 10.3):

[image: library]

[image: imageView]

> Update

Or, as pointed out by the OP in the comments, the `Library` can also be opened via menu:
`View / Libraries / Show Library` (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>)

[image: viaMenu]

Comment: I am going with your answer but the part that is missing that you may want to add for future viewers is that we must go to View --> Libraries --> Show Library and then type Image View. That was nowhere in the docs I was using. I almost posted my own answer, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, indeed. Nice addition. I updated the answer as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! That was the detail that had me stumped for awhile.